# GDI+ Graphics object does not reflect to window resize

Tags: winforms, resize, gdi+, hwnd

I've got a following problem. I'm drawing on a Windows Form's Panel surface, using native GDI+ (drawing algorithm is inside native DLL, called by P/Invoke). Everything is OK, but just until one changes size of the panel. If it is shrinked, it's being rendered properly. However, if it is enlarged, only the portion of Panel's area, that corresponds to its original size is redrawn by GDI+.

Why is it so? Do I really have to create new Graphics object every time, when the Panel resizes?

Comment: The code is probably using Graphics::FromHWND().  It is a common mistake to store that object and reuse it later.  Only draw when Windows asks you to, use the Graphics object that you get handed to you in the event arguments.  It will always have a proper clip area.

Comment: Why is it so? I have to create many GDI+ objects while drawing, so I store them and reuse later - as well as Graphics object itself. AFAIR, I've read somewhere in MSDN docs, that one shall do so to prevent unnecessary (costly, in terms of performance) memory operations.

Comment: You found out why, the Graphics object no longer matches the state of the window.  You are assuming that it is expensive to create.  It isn't, it only costs couple of dozen microseconds.  It is only expensive to keep it around, needlessly using memory.  Anyhoo, you need to recreate it when the window state changes.

Comment: Shame you've answered in the form of comment rather than regular answer, because I cannot accept it now (in terms of stackoverflow, of course) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Hans Passant in comment:

`You found out why, the Graphics object no longer matches the state of the window. You are assuming that it is expensive to create. It isn't, it only costs couple of dozen microseconds. It is only expensive to keep it around, needlessly using memory. Anyhoo, you need to recreate it when the window state changes.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing the drawing in the panel's paint event...  If this isn't the case, please let me know.

Try calling .Invalidate on the panel when it resizes.

Comment: I'm drawing in overridden OnPaint method. Adding Invalidate doesn't change anything, the redrawn area still clipped to window's original size. To be clear: the control itself is being redrawn. The problem is, that the redrawn area is clipped to control's original size.